# Read specific line of file in Python without filling memory

Tags: python, file, memory, file-read

I'm trying to read through a very large text file (> 1.5gb) line by line but would like to avoid loading the whole file into memory, is there a way to just read a specific line at once without loading everything first?

Comment: It's easy enough to do this without loading the whole file *at once*, but probably impossible to do it without at some point loading every part of the file up to the line you want, as there's no way to figure out where the `n`th line is without reading all the lines before it.

Answer (score 3):

To read every line one by one you can do

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
  for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Actually when you `open` a file, you will just get a file handle of the file. The file is never fully loaded in memory unless you specifically want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what byte offset the line exists at, you can use [seek](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) to move the file handle's current position to just the line you want. Of course, to find that offset, you'll need to count newlines or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an index built or fixed length records, you'll probably need to read the file, one line at a time, throwing out early values until you get the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just iterate over the file:

```
from itertools import count
with open('myfile') as f:
    line_index = 10
    c = count()
    while next(c) < line_index-1:
        next(f)
    my_line = next(f)
```

This would only load in one line at the time, and throw away the result until you reach the desired line.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, readlines could also do this, the default readlines without arguments will keep reading until got an EOF, but provided the extra arguments, it will read the size data at most.

You could find it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines.)

Answer (score 0):

**Print only one specified line** without loading the whole file:

```
line = 19
with open(full_name, encoding='utf8') as f:
    [next(f) for x in range(line-1)]
    print(next(f))
```

**Print only first `n` lines** without loading the whole file:

```
n = 5
with open(r'C:\Temp\test.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    head = [next(f) for x in range(n)]
print(*head, sep='')
```